# Eager load relationships in laravel with conditions on the relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have categories related to each other in a tree. Each category `hasMany` children. Each end category `hasMany` products.

The products also `belongsToMany` different types.

I want to eager load the categories with their children and with the products but I also want to put a condition that the products are of a certain type.

This is how my categories Model looks like

```
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
}


public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Product', 'category_id', 'id');
}
```

The Product Model

```
public function types()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(type::class, 'product_type');
}
```

In my database I have four tables:
category, product, type, and product_type

I've tried eager loading like so but it loads all the products and not just the ones that fulfil the condition:

```
$parentLineCategories = ProductCategory::with('children')->with(['products'=> function ($query) {
        $query->join('product_type', 'product_type.product_id', '=', 'product.id')
            ->where('product_type.type_id', '=', $SpecificID);
    }]])->get();
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of the current query, try if this fits your needs.
(I modified my answer as follows with your comment)

```
$parentLineCategories = ProductCategory::with([
            'children' => function ($child) use ($SpecificID) {
                return $child->with([
                    'products' => function ($product) use ($SpecificID) {
                        return $product->with([
                            'types' => function ($type) use ($SpecificID) {
                                return $type->where('id', $SpecificID);
                            }
                        ]);
                    }
                ]);
            }
        ])->get();
```

Comment: That still gives me all the products

Comment: are you looking for `products` related to `children` or the parent `category`

Comment: Please check if it's not a data issue. i.e all `product` belonging to same `parent category`

Comment: I'm looking to get the products related to the children categories. I'm getting the categories and their children categories which is good. The problem is with the products I want them to be loaded based on a constraint (that they are of a type which I specify). So far I am getting all the products of a child category. I want to filter that result.

Comment: Was this helpful?

Comment: Yes it was very helpful. Thank you. However instead of $child->whereHas I used $child->with. Can you update your answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Thank you... it helped me also.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) to limit your results based on the existence of a relationship as:

```
ProductCategory::with('children')
            ->with(['products' => function ($q) use($SpecificID) {
                $q->whereHas('types', function($q) use($SpecificID) {
                    $q->where('types.id', $SpecificID)
                });
            }])
            ->get();
```